# Android: is it possible to use Firebase Remote Config in a background service?

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-remote-config

I would like to use Firebase Remote Config in a background service (that I used to display notifications). Is it possible to do this ?

To be more accurate, is it possible to fetch the remote values in a background service ?

```
// Code below in a background service ?
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             // get remote values here            

    }
 }
```

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to my own question ! YES, it is possible, simply remove the 'this' in the addOnCompleteListener. It gives :

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             // get remote values here            

    }
 }
```

Seems to work perfectly in a background service.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to run Firebase Remote Config from an `IntentService` in a different process. I had to fire the `fetch` command from the `onStart` function rather than from the `onHandleIntent` one.

Comment: `onComplete` is never called in my case, do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to read manual? https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android

```
 @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Succeeded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                    // values are returned.
                    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                displayWelcomeMessage();
            }
```

Comment: You conveniently ignored the line directly before what you copied: `.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {`. `this` in that context is an activity.